# Defer component rendering using directive

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Is it possible to lazy load an element after a set amount of time has passed, using a directive?

The following is what I intend to accomplish:

In footer-container.html

```
<template [ngIf]="flag">
    <footer></footer>
<template>
```

In footer-container.ts

```
flag = false;

setTimeout(() => {
    this.flag = true;
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
}, 1000);
```

Directive would be consumed as follows:

In footer-container.html

```
<footer [defer]="1000"></footer>
```

Comment: Yes, it's done like that. What is the problem that you have with the approach you've shown?

Comment: A directive would be reusable, without adding all the boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a structural directive like ngFor and ngIf. See the documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

You can use it like that:

```
  <my-dir *delay="let delay from delay"></my-dir>
```

here is plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/mqU597fm3cdl21VYqcX5?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dir',
  template: 'hi there'
})
export class MyDir {

}

@Directive({
  selector: '[delayFrom]'
})
export class Delay implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() delayFrom: number;

  constructor(private tpl: TemplateRef<any>, private vc: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {        
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
    }, this.delayFrom);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-dir *delay="let delay from delay"></my-dir>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;
  delay = 5000;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `let delay from delay` if I may ask? Would it be possible to pass in the delay like so: `<my-dir *delay="5000"></my-dir>`

Comment: yes, you can can write it with just *delay="delay" https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtR80WyTXMUDvfF0ANdr